# Accounts only seem to be so associated

Tags: feature-request

It sure would be nice to have the option to see activity for all StackExchange sites in one place. StackExchange may have compartmentalized things but it is all just business to me. Whether I am using OnStartups, StackOverflow, ProWebmasters or anything else, I would like to see all activity in one place.

Comment: Are you referring to something different than what the StackExchange drop down does in the upper left corner of every site?

Comment: I doubt it -- that's just an inbox. The OP asked about all activity (rep, responses, badges, etc.) presumably.

Comment: @Gabe, you presumed correctly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the browser extensions for that kind of thing, [the Stack Exchange Chrome extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/1592/stack-exchange-notifier-chrome-extension) is a good one.

[image]

Comment: While the extension is pretty sweet, it is a shame it requires an extension.